# bootstrap nav-tabs didn't affect the multiple tab-content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this code from bootstrap.. and its good to use, but my problem is, it didn't affect the other tabs when duplicate, what I want is a single ID to all tabs. How can I do that? or what is the best solution..

[**SITE**](http://convolutermachine.com/convoluter.php)

sorry if my question is hard to understand or misleading..

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/9OluyI6CEN)

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this by just adding unique ids to your nav-tabs hrefs and tab panes.  Id's are supposed to be unique (meaning one per page) so if you have one #profile then then next one you will have to make it #profile2 or something to that effect.  But if you don't want to mess with adding a bunch of different id's to your page you can manually add and remove the active and in classes to your tab content and to the nav-tabs with jquery by yourself.  Then you will have to use jquerys index() function to find the number of element that you clicked on and add the corresponding classes the the right tab-pane.  Also you will not get the fade effect with the following example.

So you can remove the id's from your tab-panes and #tabtarget from the href of your nav-tabs and just use the following markup:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane in active">
      <h3>Tab 1 Tab List 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 2 Tab List 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 3 Tab List 1</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 4 Tab List 1</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane in active">
      <h3>Tab 1 Tab List 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 2 Tab List 2</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 3 Tab List 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 4 Tab List 2</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane in active">
      <h3>Tab 1 Tab List 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 2 Tab List 3</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 3 Tab List 3</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
      <h3>Tab 4 Tab List 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then use the following jquery code to achieve your desired result:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tabIndex = $('.nav-tabs a').index(this);
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
      $('.tab-pane:eq( '+tabIndex+' )').siblings().removeClass("in active");
      $('.tab-pane:eq( '+tabIndex+' )').addClass("in active");
  });
});
```

Here is a fiddle to show you this in action [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/1xmqddg9/)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question, the href's need to be unique along with the associated divs of the panel. [bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/gvrMdxRESx) - Like this:

```
<div>
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">a</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">b</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">c</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">d</div>
  </div>
  <br>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home2" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages2" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings2" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home2">e</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile2">f</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages2">g</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings2">h</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your output is correct sir, but what I want sir is I gonna use the same ID for all nav-tabs so that I wont need to create ID every time I add a new one.

Comment: @misdirection, you have to keep Dom ID elements unique. According to the WC3 "The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document)."